# Help parsing S-Expression

Tags: c++, parsing, s-expression

I'm trying to make a simple drawing program that reads in `translate (rect 10 10 10 10) 50 50`. What I'm trying to do is split it so that the `50 50` goes with the `translate` and the `rect` keeps all the `10`s.

This is a PostScript fill. I've heard of hash tables and stacks, but I'm not sure how to use them. I've done everything else (e.x. all the calculations for the shapes). I just don't understand how to parse the lines so that I can get the numbers pointing to the right variables.

Comment: Can you show us what you've got so far so that we can help?

Comment: You need help asking questions on Stack Overflow, I think!

Comment: Just because you say *"This is a PostScript fill"* I find myself wonder why you don't reverse the string on a word wise basis and parse it as a stack based, postfix command language like...well...postscript. Or you can read tokens from the back of the string. Of course, if you do that you don't need the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks like a Lisp s-expression, so try searching for "s-expression parser".  A few hits come up.

If you want to go "whole hog", you could implement your shape routines as C++ classes, use SWIG to expose them to GNU Guile, and write your application in Scheme.  That is probably not what you had in mind, though.  :-)

Comment: well im limited to C++ and i am unable to use pre made libraries.. and my ideas are hash tables, stacks, and arrays... im just not sure how to use these to read in the line

Comment: @Jr Tim: "unable to use premade libraries"... please do explain.  StackOverflow allows asking questions about homework (as long as the instructor gives permission), but you should clearly say it's homework.  And if it's not, a better description of what libraries you can and can't use (and why) would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might be a little old-fashioned, but it's simple and there's nothing faster.

```
void scanWhite(char*& p){
  while(*p==' ') p++;
}

bool seeInt(char*& p, int& num){
  scanWhite(p);
  char* p1 = p;
  bool bNegative = false;
  if (*p=='-'){bNegative = true; p++;)
  if (!isdigit(*p){p = p1; return false;}
  num = 0;
  while(isdigit(*p)){
    num *= 10;
    num += (*p - '0');
    p++;
  }
  if (bNegative) num = - num;
  return true;
}

bool seeWord(char*& p, char* word){
  scanWhite(p);
  int len = strlen(word);
  if (strncmp(p, word, len)==0 && !isalphanumeric(p[len])){
    p += len;
    return true;
  }
  else return false;
}

bool seeChar(char*& p, char c){
  scanWhite(p);
  if (*p != c) return false;
  p++;
  return true;
}

bool parseTranslateRect(char*& p
  , int& x0, int& y0, int& x1, int& y1
  , int& dx, int& dy
  )
{
  if (!seeChar(p, '(')) return false;
  if (!seeWord(p, "translate")) return false;
  if (!seeChar(p, '(')) return false;
  if (!seeWord(p, "rect")) return false;
  if (!seeInt(p, &x0)) return false;
  if (!seeInt(p, &y0)) return false;
  if (!seeInt(p, &x1)) return false;
  if (!seeInt(p, &y1)) return false;
  if (!seeChar(p, ')')) return false;
  if (!seeInt(p, &dx)) return false;
  if (!seeInt(p, &dy)) return false;
  if (!seeChar(p, ')')) return false;
  return true;
}
```

If you've got many copies of "(translate (rect ...", just call the parse routine over and over until it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can write this C++ parser using [AXE library](http://www.gbresearch.com/axe/Default.aspx):

```
Rect r;
auto rect = "(rect " 
    & r_decimal(r.left) & space 
    & r_decimal(r.top) & space
    & r_decimal(r.right) & space
    & r_decimal(r.bottom) & space
    & ')';

Point t;
auto translate = "translate " & rect 
    & space & r_decimal(t.x) 
    & space & r_decimal(t.y);
// test it
std::string str("translate (rect 10 10 10 10) 50 50");
auto match = translate(str.begin(), str.end());
```

That will parse a single translate statement in PS file. If you need to parse all translate statements and don't care to write a full blown parser for postscript format, you can use `*r_find(translate)` rule to skip input that you don't care about. `r_find(R)` rule searches the input until the rule `R` is found. Now that's pretty easy and it will also generate very fast code, probably faster than hand-written with "if"-s and "else"-s.

Disclaimer: I din't test the code above, so minor errors are possible.